# Syntax highlighting for Dockerfile in Sublime Text?

Tags: docker, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, dockerfile

Is it possible to get syntax highlighting for a Dockerfile in Sublime Text?

Comment: Not the best answer but: atom.io has a plugin for Dockerfiles

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Of course you can, by installing this package from [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation):

- Dockerfile Syntax Highlighting, https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Dockerfile%20Syntax%20Highlighting

Answer (score 17):

**for mac**

```
Press cmd(⌘)-shift-p and type "add repo".
Then paste in the GitHub address for this package:
```

https://github.com/jaytaylor/Dockerfile.sublime-syntax

```
Press cmd(⌘)-shift-p and type "install".
Enter "Dockerfile.sublime-syntax" and press enter.
```

**for windows**

```
the same just replace cmd(⌘) with Ctrl
Now you're all set! Enjoy!
```

Comment: FYI, these instructions are for **Sublime Text 3**. Instructions for 4 are in the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71745393/482115

Answer (score 10):

#### 4 Steps

1. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to [open](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) the 'Command Palette'.
2. Search: ***package control: install package*** (you may have to install it first if you haven't yet)
3. Then search: ***dockerfile syntax highlighting***
4. Close and re-open your Dockferfile, it will be syntax highlighted.

Comment: FYI, these instructions are for **Sublime Text 4**

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, Dockerfile extension for sublime Text editor:-

Steps:-

1. Press cmd(⌘)+shift+p and type "add repo".
2. Paste in the GitHub address for this package:
   https://github.com/jaytaylor/Dockerfile.sublime-syntax
3. Press cmd(⌘)+shift+p and type "install".
4. Enter "Dockerfile.sublime-syntax" and press enter.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone has same issue, in the docker-compose file, you can append the `lower_case_table_names` config to the mysql command.

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: shiftmonitor_mysql
    command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=0
```

And it works.

Comment: Your answer is unrelated to the question, maybe you replied to the wrong thread?